# How can I process Timer was canceled error?

Tags: android

I use android. 
recently I coding a resend data.
but occur illegalstateexception Timer was canceled.

This is my logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid.util.NetworkChangeReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer was canceled
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2414)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer was canceled
                                                     at java.util.Timer.scheduleImpl(Timer.java:561)
                                                     at java.util.Timer.schedule(Timer.java:459)
                                                     at kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid.sender.DataSender.sendPicData(DataSender.java:251)
                                                     at kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid.sender.DataSender.restart(DataSender.java:425)
                                                     at kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid.sender.DataSender.update(DataSender.java:337)
                                                     at java.util.Observable.notifyObservers(Observable.java:138)
                                                     at kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid.util.AutoObservable.notifyObservers(AutoObservable.java:13)
                                                     at kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid.main.Agency.notifyMessage(Agency.java:88)
                                                     at kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid.util.NetworkChangeReceiver.onReceive(NetworkChangeReceiver.java:200)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2407)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

I think this is the part where exception is occuring

```
private Timer mTimer = null; //global variable

@Override 
public void run() {
mTimer = new Timer();
...
}
@Override
public void update(){
if (this.senderState == SenderState.STOPPED) {
            this.mTimer.cancel();
    this.restart();   //Timer exception ...
        }
```

Can i know where i am going wrong?

Comment: You can't restart a canceled timer.  You need to create a new one.

Comment: @GabeSechan   your advice not use cancel, restart in same method?

Comment: You can use restart on your DataSender object.  But you have to create a new Timer object, not just start the same one.

Comment: `if (this.senderState == SenderState.STOPPED) {                                                   this.mTimer.cancel();                                                                              this.restart();}        this.mTimer = new Timer();`             this ? is same error

Comment: You need to make the new timer before you call restart

Comment: thanks, I try above restart()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally don't like to use the `java.util.Timer` class. This is mainly because of the fact that it cannot be restarted when you `cancel()` it.

Normally I would use `javax.swing.Timer` but I don't think you can use it in android. In Android, I think you should create your own timer class that encapsulates the `android.os.Handler` class.

This is how you would do it:

The `Handler` class contains a method called `postDelayed`. It will run a `Runnable` with a delay.

Let's say you want to create a timer that runs something every 1000 ms, you can create a handler and call `postDelayed(someRunnable, 1000)`.

Then here comes the interesting part. The `someRunnable` above should *also* call `postDelayed` after executing whatever you like. This way, a "loop" is formed.

"But how can I stop the handler? And how can I change the interval after it has started?" you asked.

To add a pause method to the timer class, just create a field called `paused` and check its value before calling `postDelayed` in the runnable. You can then add setters and getters that set and get the value of `paused`.

To change the interval when the timer has started, just create another field called `interval` and implement it in a similar fashion.

**TL;DR**

I am very nice, ya know. Here is the code to copy:

```
import android.os.Handler;

public class Timer {
    private Handler handler;
    private boolean paused;

    private int interval;

    private Runnable task = new Runnable () {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!paused) {
                Timer.this.runnable.run ();
                Timer.this.handler.postDelayed (this, interval);
            }
        }
    };

    private Runnable runnable;

    public int getInterval() {
        return interval;
    }

    public void setInterval(int interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    public void startTimer () {
        paused = false;
        handler.postDelayed (task, interval);
    }

    public void stopTimer () {
        paused = true;
    }

    public Timer (Runnable runnable, int interval, boolean started) {
        handler = new Handler ();
        this.runnable = runnable;
        this.interval = interval;
        if (started)
            startTimer ();
    }
}
```